# Gazebo Fortress - Need some help to add the GridConfig to the SDF file

Tags: gazebo-plugin, ignition-fortress

I'm trying to configure the grid size in the SDF file and here is what I have in the SDF file:

```
<sdf version="1.8">

<world name="demo">
    <plugin filename="GridConfig" name="ignition::gui::GridConfig">
      <ignition-gui>
        <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
      </ignition-gui>
      <insert>
        <horizontal_cell_count>60</horizontal_cell_count>
        <vertical_cell_count>20</vertical_cell_count>
        <cell_length>2</cell_length>
        <pose>1 2 3  0 0 0</pose>
        <color>1 0 0 1</color>
      </insert>
    </plugin>
    
    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
    
</world>

</sdf>
```

When I launch the ign gazebo, it gives me the following error:
`[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:117] Failed to load system plugin [ignition::gui::GridConfig] : system not found in library  [GridConfig] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libGridConfig.so].`

My gazebo version is Fortress:

```
USER:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ign gui --versions
6.8.0
```

and here is the plugin info:

```
USER:~/workspace/ros-projects$ ign plugin -vi -p /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libGridConfig.so
Loading plugin library file [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libGridConfig.so]
Loader State
    Known Interfaces: 1
        ignition::gui::Plugin
    Known Plugins: 1
        [ignition::gui::GridConfig]
            has no aliases
            implements 1 interface:
                ignition::gui::Plugin
```

Will really appreciate your help!

Comment: It turns out it's easier to update the gui.config. We can add the following code to  the gui.config: 
```
<plugin filename="GridConfig" name="Grid Config">
    <ignition-gui>
      <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
    </ignition-gui>
    <insert>
      <horizontal_cell_count>100</horizontal_cell_count>
      <vertical_cell_count>0</vertical_cell_count>
      <cell_length>1</cell_length>
      <color>1 1 1 0.7</color>
    </insert>
</plugin>
```
and disable the grid of the world in SDF file.